# In what jurisdictions is trespassing a criminal matter?

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction

In England trespass in itself is an entirely civil matter, but in the US it is apparently a crime. What other jurisdictions treat the fact of having improperly tread on another’s property as a crime?

Comment: The USA is comprised of numerous states, each of which can enact and enforce its own trespassing laws; criminal or civil.  Simply "treading upon the property of another" is not necessarily a crime in the entire USA.  For example, in the state of New Hampshire,  it must be proven that the "criminal trespasser" knowingly enters or remains in a place for which he has no license or privilege AND either committed damage, or it was an occupied dwelling or "secured premises" (enclosed or posted).  Otherwise it is a criminal "violation", which is punishable by a fine, but not technically a "crime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trespass is indeed a criminal offense in every U.S. jurisdiction of which I am aware, in addition to being a tort that can be enforced in a lawsuit without involving the criminal justice process.

For example, in Colorado, which is typical, trespass can be: [first-degree trespassing](https://www.shouselaw.com/co/defense/laws/trespassing/1st-degree/) (Colo. Rev. Stat. § 18-4-502), [second-degree trespassing](https://www.shouselaw.com/co/defense/laws/trespassing/2nd-degree/) (Colo. Rev. Stat. § 18-4-503), or [third-degree trespassing](https://www.shouselaw.com/co/defense/laws/trespassing/3rd-degree/) (Colo. Rev. Stat. § 18-4-504). As noted in the final link above:

> Colorado Revised Statute § 18-4-504 defines third-degree trespass as
> unlawfully entering or remaining on another’s property that is not
> enclosed or fenced. Third-degree trespass is typically a Colorado
> petty offense, carrying up to 10 days in jail and/or a fine of up to
> $300.

First and second degree trespass involves different kinds of property and aggravating factors.

Many countries in Europe have a "[right to roam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam)" which legalizes, and immunizes people doing it from civil and criminal liability, what is called "third-degree trespassing" in Colorado, but not trespassing in buildings or fenced or enclosed areas. But, in Colorado, the right to roam is limited to travel on rivers and streams and lakes when you do not touch the steam bed or lake bed (i.e. the "[right to float](http://lawreview.colorado.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/10.-Helton-FINAL_s.pdf)") established in the state constitution. As Wikipedia explains at this link:

> In Scotland, Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden, Estonia, Latvia,
> Lithuania, Belarus, Austria, the Czech Republic and Switzerland, the
> freedom to roam takes the form of general public rights which are
> sometimes codified in law. The access is ancient in parts of Northern
> Europe and has been regarded as sufficiently fundamental that it was
> not formalised in law until modern times. However, the right usually
> does not include any substantial economic exploitation, such as
> hunting or logging, or disruptive activities, such as making fires and
> driving offroad vehicles.

In the Western United States, the lack of a right to roam is mitigated by the fact that a very large percentage of all land is publicly owned. A majority of land is federal land in Nevada, Utah, Idaho, Alaska, and Oregon. None federal public lands probably tip this over to a majority in Wyoming and California as well.

For example, a large share of cattle grazing is done on public lands for which ranchers rent grazing rights, rather than on private lands, so it is not trespassing to enter onto that land. The map below shows the percentage of federal land in each state, but omits state and local and Indian Reservation public lands.

[image]

([Source](https://wisevoter.com/state-rankings/federal-land-by-state/))

There is very little public land, in contrast, in all but a few states in the Eastern United States.

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

The *Criminal Code* makes it a summary offence to trespass at night ([s. 177](https://Every%20person%20who,%20without%20lawful%20excuse,%20loiters%20or%20prowls%20at%20night%20on%20the%20property%20of%20another%20person%20near%20a%20dwelling-house%20situated%20on%20that%20property%20is%20guilty%20of%20an%20offence%20punishable%20on%20summary%20conviction.))

> Every person who, without lawful excuse, loiters or prowls at night on the property of another person near a dwelling-house situated on that property is guilty of an offence punishable on summary conviction.

And various provincial statutes make it a "regulatory" or "public-welfare" offence to trespass (e.g. [*Trespass Act*, R.S.B.C. 2018, c. 3](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/18003), s. 2; [*Protection of Property Act*, R.S.N.S. 1989, c. 363](https://nslegislature.ca/sites/default/files/legc/statutes/protect.htm), s. 3(1)).

Answer (score 2):

> *In England trespass in itself is an entirely civil matter.*

This has exceptions. This site by [claims.co.uk](https://www.claims.co.uk/knowledge-base/land-law/trespass) says

> **Criminal trespass**
>
> Since 2012, it is a criminal offence to trespass in residential property, effectively criminalising squatting. Under section 144 of the Legal Aid, Sentencing and Punishment of Offenders Act 2012 it is an offence for someone to be in a residential building as a trespasser, having entered as a trespasser; and that person knows or ought to know that they are a trespasser; and they are living in the building or intend to live there for any period.
>
> The police have powers to permit forced entry and arrest for this offence. On conviction, an individual may be jailed for up to 51 weeks, or receive a fine up to level 5.

---

As for the 'travelling community' setting up on public or private land, this article in the [UK House of Common Library](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/sn05116/) states:

> Section 61 of the CJPO Act enables senior officers to direct those in an unauthorised encampment to leave land if they are in an encampment that consists of six or more vehicles...
>
> ... Failure to comply with a police direction to leave is an offence.

This is why most trespassing encampments rarely consist of more than 5 caravans.

Comment: Ok but in general and until relatively recently it was a civil matter. And residential premises is an exception, not the rule.

Comment: @Seekinganswers land itself isn't "residential premises" in the second part. You stated "an entirely civil matter" but here are two examples of where it may be a criminal matter, and they aren't exceptional. People have been trespassing as squatters for centuries, and the law now makes it a criminal offence, whether it is in a building or on the land.